# Best way to invoke Cloud Run from Firebase hosted website

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-run

I am hosting my website on Firebase hosting service, and there is a scenario when a user can submit a payload which gets processed on the backend side ( Cloud Run) and it returns a result. Is it a good practice to enable CORS for cloud run and just post a https request from front-end directly to the Cloud Run endpoint? Or is it better to create a proxy cloud function and use the front-end firebase-function api to call it? Does a proxy function makes the process significantly slower ? Or does it make it more secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on the way that you prefer or want to do. As per the official documentation [Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) it indicates:

> Using Cloud Run, you can deploy an application packaged in a container image. Then, using Firebase Hosting, you can direct HTTPS requests to trigger your containerized app.

So, using the HTTPS front requests would work as you mentioned. Usually, users, it's more used with the enabling of CORS and using the HTTPS requests.

However, as per this article - [Cloud Run and Cloud Function: What do I use? And Why?](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1) - using containers and Cloud Functions seems to be the best option, due to its Portability and Testability. I would recommend you take a look at this article and make your own mind, on what do you think would fit better your needs and your future development.

Regarding performance and security, it should not affect significantly the performance of your function's calls, since these calls are not very heavy to be run. However, it should improve the security, since it will have an additional layer between your application and your database.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hi,the article looks great, but I feel like it does not solve my question. I'll edit my question with additional aspect I am curious about like how badly can affect the performance if adding a cloud fucntion as proxy or does it increase the security.

Comment: Hi @MarkPintye I have updated my answer with update information, answering your question.